# Houndify Speech to Text leaves SpokenRespons blank

Tags: node.js, speech-recognition, houndify

I have the sample houndify web client working, which shows the user utterance. The node server is also working and showing the voice object, but it's leaving the utterance as blank. STATUS is OK
Is it because it's running on a local server?

Note: My goal captures the streaming audio from the browser (check) and send houndify Speech to Text only (check) and get in in the node server. (almost)

This is my server.js :

```
var voiceRequest = new Houndify.VoiceRequest({
  clientId: config.clientId,
  clientKey: config.clientKey,

  requestInfo: {
    UserID: "test_user",
    Latitude: 37.388309,
    Longitude: -121.973968
  },

  // Sample rate of input audio
  sampleRate: 16000,

  // convertAudioToSpeex: true,

  // Enable Voice Activity Detection, default: true
  enableVAD: true,

  // Partial transcript, response and error handlers
  onTranscriptionUpdate: (transcript) => {
    console.log("Partial Transcript:", transcript.Response);
  },

  onResponse: (response, info) =>{
    console.log('->',response);
    console.log('iiii->',info);
  },

  onError: (err, info) => {
    console.log(err);
  }
})
```

[image]

---

server result:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some more information about your setup: how does your browser and node.js server interact ? 
Also could you somehow share your networking tab, ? it would help.

Comment: Well. Yes. The screenshot above with the icons is from my browser. Press the button  and send the request to houndify and prints the result in the browser as shown and to nodejs server.  Except some of the fields that print fine in the browser.. don't get back to server

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I can't tell why the response does not go back to the server, I guess you have followed the  https://github.com/soundhound/hound-sdk-web-example or https://www.npmjs.com/package/houndify

Comment: Let me grab some more info, because I don't understand fully how to get all the server tweaks.
Do the text queries work ? Can you send a text query and get a response ? Have you tried to send the request from CLI ?